# Selenium Java error when handling ShadowHost Element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I get an error when trying to manipulate the "h1" tag element because I can't expand the second shadowHost

I'm using Selenium version 4.11 with chrome and drive version 117.

What could I do to manipulate this element, or rather what am I doing wrong that I can't expand the second shadowHost, because I can manipulate/expand the first one correctly.

This is the method I use to try to manipulate

[image]

```java
 public String getElementShadow() {
        WebElement shadowHost = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("canal360i-wrapper-mfe-shadowdom"));
        SearchContext shadowRoot = shadowHost.getShadowRoot();
        WebElement shadowHost2 = shadowRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector("mf-boleto-generico"));
        SearchContext shadowRoot2 =  shadowHost2.getShadowRoot();

        String retorno = shadowRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector("h1")).toString();

        return retorno;
}
```

error

```
page funcao boletagem foi acessada    
         # steps.BoletagemSteps.validar_page_boletagem()
      org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"mf-boleto-generico"}
  (Session info: chrome=117.0.5938.132)
```